# After upgrading to MVC 5, my site returns a 404 error when published to production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, webdeploy

I recently upgraded my application from MVC 4/ EF 5 to MVC 5 / EF 6. I also upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 from VS 2012. Everything runs great on the IIS Express but when I publish to my production server via webDeploy, the site returns a 404 for all pages.

I am running IIS 8. There are no entries in my IIS log from today so this is not logging. I see no event alerts either.

I have done some research and performed the following:

1. Set the System.Web.MVC, System.Web.Routing and
   System.Web.Abstractions to use a local copy when publishing. This
   had no effect.
2. I restarted IIS.
3. I deleted all the files on the production server and re-published.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem had to do with Amazon eleastic ip - nothing wrong with the site or IIS.